# Does assigning an non-empty array to another array clear the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, variable-assignment

Say I have the arrays,

```
        string[] arr1 = { "Hi", "hello", "goodbye" };
        string[] arr2 = { "Stop", "making", "arrays", "please" };
        string[] arr3 = { "Simple", "Array"};
```

According to the declaration above `arr1` is initialized to size 3, arr2 to 4, and arr3 only 2. Now that arr1 has been initialized as an array with a maximum size 3, what happens if I assign a different array to it?

- Are the original values cleared and replaced with the new array?
- What if the second array is smaller, are only the values up to the smaller array populated and the old values kept?
- If it's bigger, do I get an IndexOutOfRange exception?

Comment: Downvoters! Since I couldn't find the answer on SO, I added the question. This was posted as a Q & A. I answered the question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried it.

```
        foreach (var item in arr1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("arr1:);   
            Console.WriteLine(" " + item);
        }

        arr1 = arr2;
        foreach (var item in arr1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("arr1 = arr2:); 
            Console.WriteLine(" " + item);               
        }

        arr1 = arr3;
        foreach (var item in arr1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("arr1 = arr3:); 
            Console.WriteLine(" " + item);
        }
```

The output is

```
arr1: 
 Hi 
 hello 
 goodbye 
arr1 = arr2:
 Stop 
 making 
 arrays 
 please 
arr1 = arr3
 Simple 
 array
```

So we see that when one array is assigned to another, the first array simply points to the same reference as the assigner (if the assigner is changed, the assigned changes identically, try it).

Answer (score 1):

The variables are pointers to arrays.  By assigning `arr2` to `arr1`, `arr1` and `arr2` both point to `{ "Stop", "making", "arrays", "please" }`.  If you assign "test" to `arr1[1]`, `arr2[1] == "test"`.  The original array assigned to `arr1` is orphaned and will be garbage collected at some point.

Answer (score 1):

The three variables in your code are just references to `System.Array` instances in memory. Assigning a different `System.Array` instance to a variable will change that variable's reference. The original `System.Array` instance will be marked for garbage collection if no other object references it.

```
string[] arr1 = { "Hi", "hello", "goodbye" };
string[] arr2 = { "Stop", "making", "arrays", "please" };
string[] arr3 = { "Simple", "Array"};

arr1 = { "A", "new", "array" }; // The original "Hi", "hello", "goodbye" array will be marked for garbage collection; arr1 now references the new array
```

I recommend reading up on reference types and garbage collection. MSDN documentation should fully explain these concepts.